# Is there any reason why my overriden setHighlighted for a UITableViewCell would not get called but the UITableViewDelegate method does?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

With Swift I'm overriding the `highlighted` property for a cell to change how it looks on highlight, but it never gets called when I tap it.

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        println("called")
    }
}
```

However, the `UITableViewDelegate` method called, `didHighlightCellAtIndexPath`, gets called every time.

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `UITableView` is actually being populated with instances of your `UITableViewCell` **subclass**. That is, make sure that `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` is actually returning an object of your `UITableViewCell` subclass. If it's not, then that property override will never be used.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that and it is indeed.

Comment: @DougSmith Hm okay. Would it be possible to see a (potentially simplified) copy of your project?